# Retry loading page on timeout with urllib2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to force Python to retry loading the page when I get a timeout error. Is there a way that I can make it retry a specific number of times, possibly after a specific time delay?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`urllib2` doesn't have anything built-in for that, but you can write it yourself.

The tricky part is that, as the [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) docs say, no matter what goes wrong, you just get a `URLError`. So, how do you know whether it was a timeout, or something else?

Well, if you look up [`URLError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError), it says it will have a `reason` which will be a `socket.error` for remote URLs. And if you look up [`socket.error`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.error) it tells you that it's a subclass of either `IOError` or `OSError` (depending on your Python version). And if you look up [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError), it tells you that it has an `errno` that represents the underlying error.

So, which `errno` value do you get for timeout? I'm willing to bet it's `EINPROGRESS`, but let's find out for sure:

```
>>> urllib.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1', timeout=0)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 36] Operation now in progress>
>>> errno.errorcode[36]
'EINPROGRESS'
```

(You could just use the number 36, but that's not guaranteed to be the same across platforms; `errno.EINPROGRESS` should be more portable.)

So:

```
import errno
import urllib2

def retrying_urlopen(retries, *args, **kwargs):
    for i in range(retries):
        try:
            return urllib2.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
        except URLError as e:
            if e.reason.errno == errno.EINPROGRESS:
                continue
            raise
```

---

If you think this sucks and should be a lot less clunky… well, I think everyone agrees. Exceptions have been radically improved twice, with another big one coming up, plus various small changes along the way. But if you stick with 2.7, you don't get the benefits of those improvements.

If moving to Python 3.4 isn't possible, maybe moving to a third-party module like `requests` or `urllib3` is. Both of those libraries have a separate exception type for `Timeout`, instead of making you grub through the details of a generic `URLError`.

Comment: I'm stuck on Python 2.7 for this project, I'll move onto 3.4 after this.

The error number is 10060 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond). It occurs randomly when the bot is running, sometimes after 5 different page loads, sometimes after 5000. I really just need a way to tell the bot to retry a number of times. I will look into changin what you posted above to fit that, thank you!

Comment: @Jake: Ah, you're on Windows, so it's `WSA_EINPROGRESS` or whatever WinSock calls it. But I'm pretty sure Python just maps `errno.EINPROGRESS` to that value anyway on Windows, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library. If you'd like to wait only for a specified amount of time (not for the entire download, just until you get a response from the server), just add the `timeout` argument to the standard URL request, in seconds:

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
```

If the `timeout` time is exceeded, it raises a `requests.exceptions.Timeout` exception, which can be handled however you wish. As an example, you could put the request in a try/except block, catch the exception if it's raised, and retry the connection again for a specified number of times before failing completely.

You might also want to check out [`requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter), which has a `max_retries` argument. It's typically used within a Requests [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session), and according to the docs, it provides a general-case interface for Requests sessions to contact HTTP and HTTPS urls by implementing the Transport Adapter interface.

Comment: I get the feeling that people who use `requests` have no idea what's in the stdlib. Yes, `requests.get(url, timeout=10)` is simple. But `urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=10)` is exactly as simple. Spending 90% of your message showing how cool `requests` is, in an area where it's no cooler than `urllib2`, hides the last line, which is the part that really matters.

Comment: @abarnert I tried to reword it some, and added some extra, potentially useful information. Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Even I am new to Python, but I think even a simple solution like this could do the trick,

begin with considering stuff as None, where stuff is page_source. Also remember that I have only considered the URLError exception. You might want to add more as desired.

```
import urllib2
import time
stuff=None
max_attempts=4
r=0
while stuff is None and r<max_attempts:
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/ncr', timeout=10)
        stuff = response.read()
    except urllib2.URLError:
        r=r+1
        print "Re-trying, attempt -- ",r
        time.sleep(5)
        pass
print stuff
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,

Md. Mohsin

Comment: But this will treat _any_ error as if it were a timeout. Not to mention that you added a 5-second sleep for some reason. So if the server rejects your connection, instead of finding out immediately that the server has rejected your connection, you'll spend 15 seconds and find out no more than that you didn't get any data for some reason.

Comment: @abarnert I understand what you are saying, but if you see the question - the question poster #1, Wants to retry if there is a timeout #2 He needs to add a time pause before retry. --- I tried to answer specifically to his needs. As already mentioned timeout is just one exception, we can add as many as we want, or just pass an exception without defining it. Time pause for 5 secs is just for example since the question required it. Of course we can pause it for n secs as required :-) And then we have max attempts as well, so it doesnt remain in the loop forever.

Comment: OK, the `time.sleep(5)` is good as an answer to the "possibly after a specific time delay" part of the question; sorry for that. But it's still not distinguishing timeouts from actual errors. You don't want to spend 15 seconds retrying something that isn't going to get better, and you don't want to swallow the error that would have told you why it didn't work.

Comment: Also, I understand why you're doing this—`urllib2` often makes it painful to distinguish different kinds of errors. That's why my answer is so complicated—as far as I know, there's no better way to solve this with `urllib2`. That's also why I asked whether he could use a third-party library that makes it easier, and why MattDMo specifically suggested one.